# Please help me to automate the application through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Please help me to automate the below  scenario through selenium webdriver

In Application values are stored in the web table.

STID STNAME AGE
1    Sachin  24
2    Kumar   25

and similarly in Database also my data stored in the student table as below

STID STNAME AGE
1    Sachin  24
2    Kumar   25

I want to compare the data from the application and database data whether data are matching or not.
Could you please provide the code for this.
Regards
Sachin

Comment: Same question as http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12584/database-and-application-data-comparision-through-selenium You will need to provide source code (HTML and Selenium) to see how far you've got and what's the actual issue.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Post the code please!

Comment: Sachin, you need to edit your original question to add this information, not simply create a duplicate with a little more information.